# Is there any ways to Perform ACID Transactions in Mongodb4.0 without using Replica Set

Tags: mongodb

We are Trying to achieve ACID transaction feature in MongoDB 4.0 for our application requirement with standalone MongoDB server, but we are facing issue with Below code snippet in Mongo Shell.

```
var session1 = db.getMongo().startSession();
var session1PersonColl = session1.getDatabase('test').getCollection('person');
session1.startTransaction({readConcern: {level: 'snapshot'}, writeConcern: {w: 'majority'}});
session1PersonColl.insert({"_id": 3, "fname": "fname-3", "lname": "lname-3"});
```

Error:

> WriteCommandError({
>           "ok" : 0,
>           "errmsg" : "Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mong os",
>           "code" : 20,
>           "codeName" : "IllegalOperation"

*Note: The same code of snippet is working fine when mongod instance started with Replica Set*

Kindly let us know if there is any way to perform this operation without Replica set

Answer (score 3):

[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) states:

> Starting in version 4.0, MongoDB provides the ability to perform multi-document transactions against replica sets.

So I suppose you do need a replica set for transaction support.

Here is another [piece of information](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/12/04/mongodb-4-0-using-acid-multi-document-transactions/):

> multi-document transactions are available for replica set deployments only. You can use transactions **even on a standalone server but you need to configure it as a replica set (with just one node)**

Comment: This guy helped me a lot. If you have MongoDB Cluster with MongOS Router(s) / Replicated Mongod Config nodes and NOT REPLICATED SHARD nodes ->>> Just enable dummy replication for SHARDED nodes without a second replica node. Then rs.initiate() for every shard node. They just be individual PRIMARY nodes only.